# inverse fourier transform coefficients

Tags: fourier-transform, python, time-series, cepstral-analysis

## Context

I want to implement (real) *cepstrum* on stock data (for example [MSFT stock](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/history?p=MSFT)) and achieve *cepstral* coefficients of this time series.

as noted in ["*Cepstral*-based clustering of financial time series"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0957417420305297), *"**(real) cepstrum** is defined as the inverse Fourier transform of the (real) logarithm of the Fourier transform of the time series"*.

so by this reference, these steps should be taken:

1. calculate Fourier transform of the time series
2. take (real) logarithm from step 1 result
3. finally calculate inverse Fourier transform of previous step

these are **steps to calculate *cepstrum* of a time series**.

## Code

implementing such process in python shouldn't be much difficult:

```
# Import Packages
from scipy.fft import rfft , irfft
import numpy as np
# pandas_datareader for reading MSFT stock data
from pandas_datareader import data as web

# ------------------------------------------

# read MSFT stock data and store it as pandas.DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(web.get_data_yahoo('MSFT' , start='01-03-2013' , end='12-06-2018')['Adj Close'])

# ------------------------------------------

# define a function to calculate cepstrum of time series
def cepstrum(x: np.array):
    """
    This Function calculate cepstrum of a time series
    """
    return irfft(np.log(rfft(x)))

# ------------------------------------------

# run cepstrum function
cepstrum(df['Adj Close'].to_numpy())
```

Output:

```
array([-0.86680682, -0.0558877 , -0.03134206, ..., -0.01719479, 0.01535661, -0.00099603])
```

As i said at first, I want to achieve cepsteral coefficients. I think cepsteral coefficients are the coefficients of *inverse Fourier transform of the (real) logarithm of the Fourier transform of the time series*. So **how can i grab coefficients of this `irfft(np.log(rfft(x)))` process?** for example i want to grab first 5 coefficient of this process. but i don't know how to access them! because `scipy` do things in backdrop!

## additional Note:

as mentioned in ["*Cepstral*-based clustering of financial time series"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0957417420305297):

> Cepstral analysis is a non linear signal processing technique. The
> **(real) cepstrum is defined as the inverse Fourier transform of the
> (real) logarithm of the Fourier transform of the time series**. In order
> to define the cepstrum, we will first consider the autoregressive
> moving average (ARMA) processes. In particular an ARMA(p, q) process
> is defined as:
>
> [image]
>
> where $\phi_r$,r = 1, 2, . . . . p are the autoregressive (AR)
> parameters, $\theta_r$, r = 1, 2, . . . , q are the moving average
> (MA) parameters and $\epsilon_t$, is a white noise process. The
> spectral density of an ARMA(p, q) process is defined as:
>
> [image]
>
> where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $\epsilon_t$. The logarithm of an
> estimated spectral density function can be approximated using an
> exponential form for the log spectral density function namely:
>
> [image]
>
> where 0 < $\omega$ < $\pi$, and where r2 and $\psi_1$, . . . ,
> $\psi_p$ are unknown parameters. Savvides et al. (2008) introduce the
> following approximation of the log of the log spectral density
> function, namely, the spectrum of the log spectral density function,
> the cepstrum of $X_t$.
>
> [image]
>
> where $\psi_0$ = $\int_0^1 log\lambda_x(\omega)d\omega$ is the
> logarithm of the variance of the white noise process $\epsilon_t$.
> Under the absolute integrability on (0,1) of $log\lambda_x(\omega)$ ,
> the Fourier coefficients of the expansion of $log\lambda_x(\omega)$
> are defined by:
>
> [image]
>
> for k = 0, 1, 2, . . . and are referred to as the **cepstral
> coefficients**. Due to the convergence in mean square of
> $log\lambda_x(\omega)$ with increasing $p$, only a small number of
> cepstral coefficients can describe the second order characteristics of
> a time series.

I'm not familiar with signal processing knowledge. so it's possible that i inferred something wrong about the whole process. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is mostly ok, but I don't get your problem. Just print them and you will grab the coefficients `print(ifft(np.log(fft(x)))[:5])`.

One thing to correct, you can't use `rfft` and `irfft` because $\ln\mathcal{F}[x(n)]$ will break the conjugate symmetry property, and thus the cepstrum is no longer a real sequence.

As for real cepstrum, it is given by
$$
c_r(n) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{ \ln |\mathcal{F}[x(n)]| \}
$$
and you can get it by `irfft(np.log(abs(rfft(x))))`. In this case `rfft` and `irfft` is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and correction! As mentioned in [scipy.rfft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.rfft.html) `(rfft)` gives us *"discrete Fourier Transform for real input"*! nothing said about coefficients in documentation! I updated **additional Note** section, hope it help more to understand what I mean about *cepsteral coefficients*

Comment: @Shayan I don't understand what you mean by "grab coefficients of this process". You already have the cepstrum coefficients by `ifft(np.log(fft(x)))`.

Comment: Yeah I exactly understand your point. But in scipy.rfft doc, they didn't say that this function gives you coefficients. by this, I concluded that scipy.rfft gives me just series (like Fourier series) and this series created by coefficients! by this I said *"grab coefficients of this process"*.

Comment: @Shayan `fft` and `rfft` return the DFT coefficients, `ifft` and `irfft` return the time sequences. You should keep in mind about the definition of cepstrum coefficient which is given by $c(n) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{ \ln \mathcal{F}[x(n)] \}$ and `ifft(np.log(fft(x)))` is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Did you read **additional notes section**? Do you think i'm doing it in right way to achieve cepstral coefficients? Sorry I don't know much about cepstral coefficients. I fear if there's many kind of cepstral coefficients according to cepsteral context. And you mean `ifft(np.log(abs(fft(x))))` is exactly what i want?

Comment: (Because you omitted `abs` in your last comment.)

Comment: @Shayan without abs you get the cepstrum coefficient which is complex-valued, with abs you get the real cepstrum which is real-valued.